# dispatch_queue_create multiple invocations with same label

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a requirement to execute a small set of related tasks on a custom thread created for them. The tasks will be scheduled from different classes.
I'm planning to use GCD's dispatch_queue_create to create the custom thread and schedule the task on it. Note that all the related tasks must execute only on that one thread in order.
So my question is if I call **dispatch_queue_create("my_custom_thread_label", NULL)** with the same label from many classes in my codebase, would it all eventually map to just one thread? Or do I need to create it in one place and get a reference to it whenever needed? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create it in one place and pass the pointer around.

Comment: But what does happen if you do simply call `dispatch_queue_create` with the same label multiple times?

Comment: It gives you a new instance of the queue and the old one leaks, its just like an object.

Comment: odyth - that seems inconsistent with the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_queue_create.3.html The label is provided FYI only, and is (in fact) optional. You could provide a blank label. Each time you call d_q_c() it returns a *new* queue object -- no leaks.